# How to export products for only a specific website in a multi-store setup?

Tags: export

```
Magento ver. 2.4.2-p1
```

I have a Magento install with 3 unique websites. I need to export products for only 1 website at a time.

There does not appear to be an option for this in:

```
- System - Export - Entity type = Products
```

**How to best do this?**

Answer (score 0):

Run below script :

```
protected $storeManager;
protected $productCollectionFactory;
protected $csvProcessor;

public function __construct(
    StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
    Csv $csvProcessor
) {
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
    $this->csvProcessor = $csvProcessor;
}

public function execute()
{
    $websiteId = 1; // Change this to the ID of the target website

    $productCollection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
    $productCollection->addWebsiteFilter($websiteId);

    $exportData = [];
    $exportData[] = ['sku', 'name', 'price']; // Add more fields as needed

    foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
        $exportData[] = [$product->getSku(), $product->getName(), $product->getPrice()]; // Add more fields as needed
    }

    // Generate and save the CSV file
    $exportPath = $this->getExportPath(); // Define a method to get the export file path
    $this->csvProcessor->saveData($exportPath, $exportData);
}

private function getExportPath()
{
    $mediaDirectory = $this->filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::VAR_DIR);
    $exportPath = 'export/products_for_website.csv';
    return $mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath($exportPath);
}
```

Comment: Would I do this in phpMyAdmin? Or do I make it into a file and then access the file?

Comment: Create one controller and execute it at any action.and it is working.

Comment: I googled how to create a controller in Magento 2 and it seems rather complicated. There is no way for me to execute this script in phpMyAdmin? Is there an existing controller somewhere in Magento I may be able to (re)use for this and just plug your code in it?

Comment: yes you can add it in any button action controller and done that , Like on create account or login customer, or any other button action, or you know the any custom action, you can execute in.

Comment: I know this is a lot to ask but any chance you could put up steps for the easiest way to accomplish this please?

Comment: yes sure, i will give you one script, which you can used in root file and your issue is solve.

Comment: If you would please remember me - thank you.